# Window.location.href not working inside an onmessage event?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, postmessage

I have an iframe, inside the iframe there is a form, the form is loaded either empty or with errors message or success message, very basic form, no AJAX or Axios, the page refreshes with the form & success or error messages

I am using this iframe inside another website, when my form is being submitted, I have to scroll to it from the window parent, if there an error message I scroll to it for example

Did not implement that completly, because this is not my problem

This a script I added inside the form ( and iframe of course )

```
<script>
        let errors = document.getElementsByClassName("msg-error");
        let data = [];
        if(errors.length !== 0) {
            for(let i = 0; i<errors.length; i++){
                data.push(errors[i].classList[1]);
                let anchor = errors[i].getElementsByClassName("error-anchor")[0];
                anchor.id = (errors[i].classList[1] + "").trim();
            }
        }
        
        window.onmessage = function(event) {
            event.source.postMessage({message: "TESTForm", data}, event.origin);
        };
    </script>
```

I am sending a message to the hosting page! for now, if there is error message, their id are going to be sent the the hosting page

On the hosting page I have this :

```
<script>
    // Main page:
    window.onmessage = function (event) {
        if (event.data.message === "TESTForm") {
            let receivedData = event.data.data;
            console.log("JOCELYN", receivedData.length === 0);
            window.location.href = receivedData.length === 0 ? "#frmTestFrame-1" : "#" + receivedData[0];

        }
    };
</script>
```

I receive the message, how I know I am receiving them ?

`console.log` shows me when the page loads for the first time `"JOCELYN true"` as a result, & if there is an error it shows me `"JOCELYN false"`

But in either cases, I have to see an anchor in my url ? right ? in both cases, either true or false! But I don't see it at all, that my original url

Why ? I don't know, and that's why I am here!

Any help would be much appreciated really!

Comment: I think you should set `window.location.hash` instead of `window.location.href`. `window.location.hash = "#frmTestFrame-1"` should do the trick

Comment: I have been working using href instead of hash the whole time & it was doing well for me, I don't think that this is the problem and it is not because I tested with hash, same thing, the href is not working and the hash as well !